# Knowledge Articles don't show up in Content Management section of Community

Tags: community, lightning-community, knowledge, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to setup community with knowledge base in Salesforce. I have enabled Lightning Knowledge Articles, Chatter and Topics for Objects (for knowledge).
I have my Data Categories setup as well. Also I have few sample articles with some of these categories which are published. (btw I also have multi-lingual support for my org and articles.)
Now when I go to the Content Management section in the community, I set up Navigational and Featured Topics for the community. When I go to the Article Management tab, I do not see any articles that I have in my org. I have checked all the permissions per profile, community and tried almost everything at this point in terms of permissions and access but my existing knowledge articles just do not show up in the Content Management -> Topics -> Article Management tab.

Did anyone has faced such issue and how did they fix it? Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue for me when this occurred was the language selection. The Lightning Knowledge language needs to match the Community language (I had English UK when I needed to have English US). Double check it by going to Community Builder | Gear icon | Language.

Comment: yeah I think thats the issue and I have fixed the language part but the articles still don't show up